# Extending input element

Tags: dart, dart-html

i extended the html `InputElement` as the following, and tried to render it with in another custom element

```
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  document.registerElement('x-editor', EditorBase,extendsTag:'input');
  document.registerElement('x-item', Item);
}

class EditorBase extends InputElement{
  EditorBase.created():super.created();
}

class Item extends HtmlElement{

  Item.created():super.created(){
    this.createShadowRoot();
    String template = '<input  is="x-editor"></input>'
                      '<input  is="x-editor"></input>';
    this.shadowRoot.appendHtml(template);
  }
}
```

in my html i have

```
<x-item></x-item>
```

when i run chromium writes `2 Removing disallowed type extension <INPUT is="x-editor">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand what you need. But I wanna share for you one more option to extend input element:

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:html_common';
import 'package:web_components/interop.dart';

class NumericInput extends InputElement {

  NumericInput.created() : super.created() { print('created!');}

  @override
  void attached() {
    super.attached();
    print('Hi, it's is a NumericInput here!');
  }
}

//call it in `main()`
registerNumericInput() => document.registerElement('x-input', NumericInput, extendsTag: 'input');
```

Somewhere in HTML:

```
<input is="x-input" value="{{number}}">
```

You don't need to make a shadowDom. But I don't know how it's useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

this did it , i don't know why though

```
class Item extends HtmlElement{

  final NodeValidatorBuilder _htmlValidator=new NodeValidatorBuilder.common()
    ..allowElement('input', attributes: ['is']);


  Item.created():super.created(){
    this.createShadowRoot();
    String template = '<input  is="x-editor"></input>'
                      '<input  is="x-editor"></input>';
    this.shadowRoot.setInnerHtml(template,validator:_htmlValidator);
  }
}
```